# Sorting and combining data in a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries similar to this one:

```
{'Catch': 4.414, 'ShipID': 173, 'Name': u'Sigur\xf0ur \xd3lafsson SF - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 2.401, 'ShipID': 173, 'Name': u'Sigur\xf0ur \xd3lafsson SF - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 67.463, 'ShipID': 1275, 'Name': u'J\xf3n V\xeddal\xedn VE - 82', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 51.803, 'ShipID': 1275, 'Name': u'J\xf3n V\xeddal\xedn VE - 82', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 7.539, 'ShipID': 1595, 'Name': u'Fr\xe1r VE - 78', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 97.984, 'ShipID': 1903, 'Name': u'\xdeorsteinn \xdeH - 360', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 94.796, 'ShipID': 1903, 'Name': u'\xdeorsteinn \xdeH - 360', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 61.347, 'ShipID': 2020, 'Name': u'Su\xf0urey VE - 12', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 21.135, 'ShipID': 2401, 'Name': u'\xde\xf3runn Sveinsd\xf3ttir VE - 401', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 16.151, 'ShipID': 2444, 'Name': u'Vestmannaey VE - 444', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 41.213, 'ShipID': 2677, 'Name': u'Bergur VE - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 5.046, 'ShipID': 2403, 'Name': u'Hvanney SF - 51', 'Gear': u'NET'}
{'Catch': 2.311, 'ShipID': 2403, 'Name': u'Hvanney SF - 51', 'Gear': u'NET'}
{'Catch': 6.304, 'ShipID': 2403, 'Name': u'Hvanney SF - 51', 'Gear': u'NET'}
{'Catch': 4.231, 'ShipID': 2732, 'Name': u'Skinney SF - 20', 'Gear': u'NET'}
{'Catch': 6.46, 'ShipID': 2732, 'Name': u'Skinney SF - 20', 'Gear': u'NET'}
...
```

This list is pre-sorted with this:

```
list_sorted = sorted(landingList, key=lambda d:(d['Gear'], d['ShipID']))
```

This is a list of landings by ships in Iceland and what I would like to do, is to split the list up by 'Gears' and add the catch so that the total catch is displayed. Similar to this

The 'BOTN' list would be like this:

```
{'Catch': 6.815, 'ShipID': 173, 'Name': u'Sigur\xf0ur \xd3lafsson SF - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 119.266, 'ShipID': 1275, 'Name': u'J\xf3n V\xeddal\xedn VE - 82', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 7.539, 'ShipID': 1595, 'Name': u'Fr\xe1r VE - 78', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 192.78, 'ShipID': 1903, 'Name': u'\xdeorsteinn \xdeH - 360', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 61.347, 'ShipID': 2020, 'Name': u'Su\xf0urey VE - 12', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 21.135, 'ShipID': 2401, 'Name': u'\xde\xf3runn Sveinsd\xf3ttir VE - 401', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 16.151, 'ShipID': 2444, 'Name': u'Vestmannaey VE - 444', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
{'Catch': 41.213, 'ShipID': 2677, 'Name': u'Bergur VE - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
```

Then the 'NET' list would be like this:

```
{'Catch': 13.661, 'ShipID': 2403, 'Name': u'Hvanney SF - 51', 'Gear': u'NET'}
{'Catch': 10.691, 'ShipID': 2732, 'Name': u'Skinney SF - 20', 'Gear': u'NET'}
```

Of course there are more Gears and landings. But this is only to demonstrate how  the list looks like and my task at hand. Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Still don't really understand this.  Don't know what your BOTN or NET lists are - while example code is helpful can you please try to post a stand-alone question that is clear?

Comment: @djechlin: Sorry that this is unclear. The application I am writing is a web-scraping application that takes data from a web page that shows landings(I think that is the proper English term here) of ships in Iceland, and the key's of the dictionaries are the information that are relevant(Later I may add Harbour to the list but I am unsure). 

BOTN and NET are short terms for the fishing gear that was used to catch the fish in that particular fishing trip. I want to calculate the total catch of each boat and group them together by their fishing gear.

Hope this clarifies a bit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`itertools.groupby()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for gear, group in groupby(list_sorted, key=itemgetter('Gear')):
    # group is now an iterator, loop over it to get all items with the same value for Gear.
    # gear is the value of this group's "Gear" key.
```

Comment: Just see my answer, hopefully this is what you implied

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Specified the use of [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), but the implementation would not be straight forward. Here is how I was able to get this in place

```
from itertools import groupby, tee
from operator import itemgetter
from copy import deepcopy
#Create a Wrapper named combine to wrap the entire functionality
def combine(data):

    #Which has a nested function to calculate the subtotal
    #For each Gear and Name Pair
    def subtotal(data):
            #Now Iterate through the grouped Gear Items
        for k1, v1 in data.iteritems():
            #And save the current Gear
            gear = k1
            #For Each person grouped catch
            for k2, v2 in v1:
                #Save the name
                name = k2
                #Create two iterator from one
                #We need this as we don't want
                #to lose the iterator after we
                #make an entire pass to calculate
                #the total catch
                v2_1, v2_2 = tee(v2)
                #Now calculate the total catch for each person
                tot_catch = sum(e['Catch'] for e in v2_1)
                #and select the first element from the group
                v2_2 = next(v2_2)
                #and update the catch with the total catch under
                #his belt and discard the rest
                v2_2['Catch'] = catch
                #finlly yield a tuple of the subtotal row
                #along with the gear and fisherman's name
                yield (gear, name, v2_2)
    #First create a copy of the data as we would be changing it in-place
    data = deepcopy(data)
    #First Group by the Gear
    data_groupby_Gear = groupby(data, key = itemgetter('Gear'))
    #For each Gear group by the fisherman
    data_groupby_Gear_then_Name = {k: groupby(list(v), itemgetter('Name'))
                                   for k,v in data_groupby_Gear}
    #and return the combined result
    return subtotal(data_groupby_Gear_then_Name)

#Just iterate through the combined data and print
#in any way you desire
for gear, name, sumtotal in combine(data):
    print u"{:10} {:20} {}".format(gear, name, sumtotal)
```

And the final output would look like below, but the display can be reformatted as desired

```
NET        Hvanney SF - 51      {'Catch': 13.661000000000001, 'ShipID': 2403, 'Name': u'Hvanney SF - 51', 'Gear': u'NET'}
NET        Skinney SF - 20      {'Catch': 10.690999999999999, 'ShipID': 2732, 'Name': u'Skinney SF - 20', 'Gear': u'NET'}
BOTN       Sigurður Ólafsson SF - 44 {'Catch': 6.8149999999999995, 'ShipID': 173, 'Name': u'Sigur\xf0ur \xd3lafsson SF - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Jón Vídalín VE - 82  {'Catch': 119.26599999999999, 'ShipID': 1275, 'Name': u'J\xf3n V\xeddal\xedn VE - 82', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Frár VE - 78         {'Catch': 7.539, 'ShipID': 1595, 'Name': u'Fr\xe1r VE - 78', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Þorsteinn ÞH - 360   {'Catch': 192.78, 'ShipID': 1903, 'Name': u'\xdeorsteinn \xdeH - 360', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Suðurey VE - 12      {'Catch': 61.347, 'ShipID': 2020, 'Name': u'Su\xf0urey VE - 12', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Þórunn Sveinsdóttir VE - 401 {'Catch': 21.135, 'ShipID': 2401, 'Name': u'\xde\xf3runn Sveinsd\xf3ttir VE - 401', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Vestmannaey VE - 444 {'Catch': 16.151, 'ShipID': 2444, 'Name': u'Vestmannaey VE - 444', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
BOTN       Bergur VE - 44       {'Catch': 41.213, 'ShipID': 2677, 'Name': u'Bergur VE - 44', 'Gear': u'BOTN'}
```